# How to play vob file using foot pedal without skips in audio

Tags: windows-7

I have to transcribe vob files using a foot pedal where I can pause, rewind, etc.  I can play them in the software that I have, but the files "skip" frames.  They'll play and then jump further ahead in the files.  How can I overcome this problem?  I have Windows 7 Premium Home

Comment: What foot pedal? What software? The problem is likely in either one of them.

Comment: It is an Infinity foot pedal.  Start-Stop Transcription software or The Record Player software.

Comment: I've even listened to the vob files in Media Classic Player, without using a foot pedal just straight up listening without pausing or anything, and it skips frames.

Comment: Are you sure the files are OK? Try them on someone else's computer. If they are OK, it sounds like your computer is (sometimes) too busy doing other things.

Comment: Other people who do what I do have the same problem.  I have a newer computer that I don't really use except to do my work, so I don't know what the problem could be.  I converted a .mob file to a .wmv file and that seems to be okay using with a foot pedal with no skips (listening as a mob file, there were skips).